# Should have the question about the map projections been migrated?

Tags: discussion

The question about [map projections](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/which-world-map-projection-allows-comparing-countries-by-shape-and-size?noredirect=1) have been migrated to the GIS site. I seems like a too rashly decision to me, as the GIS site is merely about information systems and almost all question there are somehow computer related. It is not a general geography site, although there are probably more knowledgeable in the area of cartography.

As there is no direct geography site and think that this question should be migrated back as it better suits our faq, even if it is only implicitly travel related.

Answer (score 7):

I do get that GIS is focussed more towards the information systems side of geodata processing but given its target audience you will probably find a better answer there. The GIS.SE guys haven't really fleshed out an FAQ on what's on/off topic though. I still think it's a better fit for their site as it's for "cartographers AND GIS professionals" - a cartographer may as well have asked the same question under a different context for developing a geodata application.

Answer (score 7):

The question is interesting, but not related to travel. Moreover, on GIS it has (by now) received 9 upvotes 4 "favourites". And no dissent in the comments. Given these indicators, I think that the moderators' decision is somewhat confirmed ...